# What's the most practical way to measure angular velocity for small rotations?

Tags: measurements, sensors, circuits

I'm looking to measure the angular velocity of an arm as it moves. It seems to be a difficult thing to research, since the term 'angular velocity/frequency' is usually reserved for other areas of circuit analysis.

I imagine something like a tachometer or a generator is most practical, but I can't find anything dealing with an incomplete rotation (i.e. about 90-120 degrees). Any help or push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If all you need is angular velocity, a gyroscope is ideal.  If you need angular position as well, use a gyroscope + accelerometer + complementary filter.

Comment: Think of the reluctor ring used for abs on cars - 12 or more teeth which gives the resolution of the partial rotation of the shaft. For 90 degrees you would get 3 pulses, depending on the start point. You could consider two 12 tooth rings offset...

Comment: Any reason you can't measure position (using a potentiometer or similar) and differentiate?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a video camera and attach a striped pattern to form a moire pattern which is easy to see in the video. Here's a link: [http://www.unappel.ch/people/emin-gabrielyan/public/070804-multi-ring-moire-indicator/]

[1](https://web.archive.org/save/http://www.unappel.ch/people/emin-gabrielyan/public/070804-multi-ring-moire-indicator/)
[[image]][2](https://web.archive.org/web/20190712102656im_/http://www.unappel.ch/people/emin-gabrielyan/public/070804-multi-ring-moire-indicator/index_files/image035.gif)